# Why did we use this temp variable?

Tags: c++

why did we use the temp variable ? what does it mean in the for loop ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a, x, sqrt;
    double temp;

    cout << "type a number: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    x = 1.5;
    sqrt = 0.5 * (x + (a / x));
    cout << sqrt << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        temp = sqrt;
        sqrt = 0.5 * (sqrt + (a / sqrt));
        if (temp == sqrt) {
            return 0;
        }
        cout << sqrt << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because that is the code's logic: if the `sqrt` does not change from before the recalc, bail. A better question is why did we declare uninitialized variables at the top of the function old-school C style?

Comment: Would it be clearer if `temp` were renamed to `the_previous_value_of_sqrt`?

Comment: Wow, ancient c-style declaration of all variables up front coupled with bad naming produces hard to understand code. Who would have imagined.

Comment: If you understand the algorithm it is obvious, and if you _don't_ understand the algorithm, you're asking the wrong question. So which is it?

Comment: It even goes for bonus points by shadowing a standard library function name.

Comment: im new to coding thats why, i guess

Comment: and i dont know what u guys mean by old school c

Comment: Back in the 1970s and the bulk of the 1980s the C programming language required all variables to be declared at the top of the scope. When you're talking coding practices more than a couple decades old you might as well be discussing dinosaur husbandry.

Comment: Sadly a lot of this stuff lingers because schools are still using lesson plans developed for Cobol that have been adapted to Pascal, then to C, then to Java, or C++. Odds are whoever's teaching C++ learned C back when the old ways were the only way and have not updated their materials since then.

Comment: Programming languages, just like spoken and written ones, evolve over time as new concepts show up and require expressing, better ways of doing things are discovered, and the world generally changes around them. Historically, The C language gets an update every decade or so. C++ looks like it's on about a 3 year cycle, often with big updates followed by a sort-of bugfix smaller update before another big update

Comment: This is a good example why you should not use `namespace std;`.  There is a `sqrt` function in `namespace std;`, e.g. `std::sqrt()`.  You should rename your `sqrt` variable so there is less confusion, such as `sqrt_result`.

Comment: In addition to very bad style, using `double` type for `temp`, to copy from and even *compare* with `sqrt` which is of type `float` seems like a bug. It probably works in this direction, but I doubt the algorithm would converge if the types were inverted.

Answer (score 2):

Temp is normally just a variable name used for something that will be deleted soon or will soon become out of scope.

In this code, it is just used to check if sqrt had changed, if sqrt had not changed it can return 0. So it is temporarily storing what sqrt used to be, so then we can compare what it is now with what it used to be later.

Comment: Anyone using "temp" as variable name instead of something more descriptive should be forced to watch Kate Gregory's "Naming is Hard" talk multiple times: https://youtu.be/MBRoCdtZOYg

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using the temp variable to store the initial value of the "sqrt" variable at the start of each loop iteration, before calculating a new value for "sqrt" and comparing it against its initial value (stored in temp).

Based on your program, it will run loop until the loop condition no longer applies, or until the formula "0.5 * (sqrt + (a / sqrt));" outputs the same as its input, meaning sqrt is no longer changing.

Comment: so the value of temp doesn't change you mean ? even if its in a loop ?

Comment: The value of temp is changed, but if it's going to be changed to the same value, the algorithm is done. It has computed has far as it can.

Answer (score 1):

To some extend this question is about maths, not coding.

The coding part:

The loop stops when `sqrt` does not change after applying

```
sqrt = 0.5 * (sqrt + (a / sqrt));
```

`temp` stores the value of `sqrt` before applying that formula and is compared to `sqrt` after updating it.

The maths part can be investigated with the help of eg [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=s+%3D%3D+0.5+*+%28s+%2B+%28a+%2F+s%29%29%3B). Merely typing the above equation (`=` -> `==` and `sqrt` -> `s` to not be confused with the square root function) will tell us some information, among it also that `sqrt = - sqrt(a)` is an integer solution (ie a fixpoint of iteratively applying the update again and again.

TL;DR: The code calculates the square root of `a` by applying the same update to `sqrt` until `sqrt` does not change. To detect if `sqrt` changes, the value before (`temp`) and after is compared.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the program tries to find an approximation of the square root of `a`.

`sqrt` will become an ever better approximation.

It starts with an estimate of 1.5 and then iteratively uses the formula

```
             sqrt + a/sqrt
next sqrt =  -------------
                   2
```

When `sqrt` is larger/smaller than the real square root of a,
`a / sqrt` is smaller/larger the the real square root.
So taking the average gives a better approximation.

It sets a raw boundary of steps to `a` itself.

Every approximation is printed.

The old and new `sqrt` value need to be compared. If they are equal one should stop too. For that `temp` stores a copy of the (old) sqrt.

When there are no changes to `sqrt` (it is `a/sqrt`, close to the real square root) it would continue emitting the same value, when not exiting the program with `return 0;`.

---

You see that `x`, the initial guess of 1.5, is not really need as variable, especially with such no-name moniker. Also the approximation formula applied  redundantly on x. Of course you do not want to start every approximation sequence by outputing 1.5, but it could have been written neater.